# Extract Magento original image file from cache url

Tags: magento-1.9

An example how can i get the original image file without watermark (cache) http://media.cdn.perfectwatches.cn/media/catalog/product/cache/41/thumbnail/d58d221d145737832062eac5ca81956a/r/rl103/f.jpg

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I would to try this for [Magento development extension](https://magento.ocodewire.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the cache-related pathing:

```
http://media.cdn.perfectwatches.cn/media/catalog/product/cache/41/thumbnail/d58d221d145737832062eac5ca81956a/r/rl103/f.jpg
                                                        |--------------------- remove ----------------------|
```

But this will only work if the file is present on that server and if permissions allow.

Answer (score 0):

When opening the backend of Magento and edit the product where this image relates you, you get a thumbnail. This is actually a scaled version of the original image, so if you open that image in a new tab/window, you have the original image URL.